# html type number won't relocate

Tags: html, css, input

I am currently trying to move this number input box into a location in CSS using coordinates and so far nothing I have typed in has worked.
I've tried:

```
top: 30%;
top: 30px;
right: 40%;
right: 40px;
```

In every CSS thing and so far none of them have moved the thing here is the HTML portion of it

HTML:

```
<input class="checkout-delay" type="number" min="0" value="0">
```

CSS:

```
.checkout-delay {
    bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #bf0d33;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-color: #900926;
    height: 15px;
    width: 25px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  
   opacity: 1;
   margin: 0;
}

.input[type="number"] {
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

(PS. I would also like to be able to customize the arrows by making them bigger and changing there color but that seems impossible from the stuff I've read online about it)

Comment: top and right work only when `position` is absolute or fixed or sticky.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to put this first

```
position: absolute;
```

lol